# lombok @Data で Getter が作成されていない？

Tags: java, spring-boot

SpringToolSuite4でjavaの勉強しているところです。
lombok @Data を使って自動的にGetter,Setterなどを追加しようとしています。
しかしながら、コントローラーにはGetterがサジェストされず、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そのままブラウザからアクセスしてもエラーになります。
`Unresolved compilation problem: メソッド getName() は型 User で未定義です`

クラスの定義は次のコードで `@Data` を指定しています。

```java
package com.example.demo.models;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6647247658748349084L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 10)
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    @Email
    private String mail;

    @Size(max = 400)
    private String introduction;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String nickname;

    public void clear() {
        name = null;
        mail = null;
        introduction = null;
        nickname = null; 
    }
}
```

メインコントローラーは次のような形で呼び出しています。

```
    @GetMapping("/form3")
    public String form3(User user) {
        String nameString = user.getName();
        //略
        return "root/form3";
    }
```

lombokの公式ページを見ても、上記の設定良いように思えます。
https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

何が問題になっているのか、教えて頂けますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

【追記：2022-06-23】
nameの部分を下記のように同じlombokのGetterとSetterを追加してみました。
importも追加済みです。

```
    @NotBlank
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Size(min = 3, max = 10)
    private String name;
```

しかしながら、Controller の方で見ると表示されません。
これはIDEかlombookが正しく動作できていない用に思えます。

回答のコメントにも書きましたが、lombokの再インストールは実行済みです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
※利用できるメソッド内にgetter,setterが表示されない

【追記：2022-06-24】
次のようにコードを書いてみたところ「未定義」との警告は出ていますが、
コンパイラも通り、エラーもなく実行されました。
ということは、getter,setterはつくられているということですね。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、不思議なことにデバッグでステップインをしてみると
全くコードがないところに移動します。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
spring tool suite が正しく動作していない…と見るべきなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

[SpringToolSuite4(STS)にlombokをインストールする](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)必要があります。

[Windows10 に Java/Spring Boot 開発環境をセットアップする](https://zenn.dev/yukihane/articles/fb52d049da587c#spring-tools-4-for-eclipse(sts)-%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB-%26-%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97) から引用します:

> 1. STS を終了させます。
> 2. https://projectlombok.org/download から lombok.jar をダウンロードします。
> 3. `java -jar ~/Downloads/lombok.jar` コマンドを実行し、インストーラを起動します。
> 4. `SpringToolSuite4.exe`(例: `C:\Users\yuki\Documents\opt\sts-4.12.1.RELEASE\SpringToolSuite4.exe`) の場所を指定して **Install/Upgrade** ボタンを押してインストールします。

STS へ lombok インストールを実行すると `SpringToolSuite4.ini` 最下行に `-javaagent:/path/to/lombok.jar` という行が挿入されます。 `lombok.jar` がこのパスに存在しているか確認してみてください。

また、[オフィシャルサイト](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)にある通り、 lombok がインストールできていれば STS の About 画面(Help > About Spring Tool Suite 4)にも表れます。
こちらも想定通り出力されているか確認してみてください。

[image]

---

質問の主題からは外れますが、一般的に `@Entity` に　`@Data` を付与するのは誤りです(gette/setterが必要なら `@Getter`, `@Setter` で対応すべきです)。

- [JPA Entity には Lombok の @Data(@EqualsAndHashCode) を使用すべきでない – 発火後忘失](https://yukihane.github.io/blog/202107/31/dont-use-lombok-with-jpa/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
最初インストールしたものが不完全かと思い、まさに回答いただいた方法で再インストールを実行しました。しかしながら、解決には至りませんでした。
@Dataの部分にCtrlキーを押しながらクリックすると `Data.class` に飛びますので、インストール自体はうまく行っているのではないかと思っています。

Comment: 「一般的に  `@Entity`  に `@Data` を付与するのは誤りです」
なるほど、この部分修正するようにやってみます。

Comment: `pom.xml` あるいは `build.gradle` への lombok 設定は https://start.spring.io/ (など、生成ツール)で行なったのでしょうか、あるいは手動で追加したでしょうか。もし手動であれば、 `pom.xml`(か`build.gradle`)の内容を質問文へ追加することを検討してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

gradleを使っているのであれば
build.gradleのdependenciesに以下を追加すればうまくいくと思います。

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

※動作確認はIntelliJ IDEAを使いました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ターミナルで gradle -v を実行してみましたが、エラーとなったので未使用のようです。
loom.Data は JavaDocの表示、`Data.class` の存在からインストール、また利用できる状況にあるように思えます。
プロジェクトエクスプローラーの「Maven依存関係」にも `lombok-1.18.12.jar' が確認できます。